# How to Iterate Result in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to the robot.
I get DB result as

```
@{result}= [ ("ABC DEF",) | ('HIJ KLM',) | ("OPQ REST",) ]
```

I want to how to process result for rows received from `@{result}` and to check the row contains DEF value.

It would be thankful if anyone facing same issue and having solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your main concern is about iteration in the Robot Framework. If that's the case, try following For loop.

```
*** Variables ***

@{results}=   ABC DEF  HIJ KLM  OPQ REST

*** Test Cases ***

Iteration
    FOR    ${result}    IN    @{results}
        ${bool}   Run Keyword and ignore error     should contain any  ${result}     DEF
        log     ${bool}

    END
```

Output is as follows:

[image]